# UICollection view: align custom cells horizontally

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, alignment, uicollectionviewcell

I am setting some custom UICollectionViewCells which I'd like to align horizontally. I have set some properties as follows but seem to mis the trick somewhere.

[image]

EDIT: Here is the section inset:

[image]

EDIT: This is how I would like them to look:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am Wrong. You want all the green boxes to be horizontally aligned in the collection view(the one in pale green color) and these green boxes to be vertically centered. BTW, Can you post the sectionInset (spacing margins) you have set for the collection view in the storyboard?

Comment: It look like sectionInset is set as (0,0,0,0). SectionInset controls the top,bottom, left and right spacing margins for the cell Layout inside the collection view. Let say sectionInset is (20,10,15,30), cell layout will start at 20 pts from top of collection view,10 pts from left of collection view and similarly other spacing margins. Play with section inset and see which value suits your case.